# initWithCoder not working as expected?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Does this seem right, the dataFilePath is on disk and contains the right data, but the MSMutable array does not contain any objects after the initWithCoder? I am probably just missing something, but I wanted to quickly check here before moving on.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        [self setReactorCore:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"CORE"]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

.

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath]]) {
            NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
            NSKeyedUnarchiver *unArchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
            NSMutableArray *newCore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCoder:unArchiver];
            [self setReactorCore:newCore];
            [newCore release];
            [data release];
            [unArchiver release];
        } else {
            NSMutableArray *newCore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [self setReactorCore:newCore];
            [newCore release];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT_001**

I think I know where I am going wrong, I am archiving NSData and then trying to initialise my NSMutable array with it. I will rework the code and post back with an update.

gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused as to why you're doing things this way. You do not normally call `initWithCoder:` yourself. You ask the coder for its contents and it creates the objects for you. The whole decoding part of that method should be `id archivedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self dataFilePath]]`, where `archivedObject` is presumably the array you call `newCore` in your code (I don't know the contents of the file, so I'm just guessing from what you wrote). In that case, you'll want to `mutableCopy` it, since I don't think NS*Archiver preserves mutability.

I also hope you aren't expecting your `initWithCoder:` method that you wrote at the top of your post to be called when this NSArray is unarchived.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, I had not considered the preserving of mutability, I will go and rethink what I am doing. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

"I also hope you aren't expecting your initWithCoder: method that you wrote at the top of your post to be called when this NSArray is unarchived."

is not useful. Why can't you write why it's not called? Thanks

**EDIT:**
In fact, if the objects in your array implement NSCoding, initWithCoding is called on each of them when you restore your array (restore here means that you call [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"yourArray"]). I'm actually doing this in my own code. So I think what you wrote is false!